# How to get multiple arrays and associated views respectively from theses arrays?

Tags: arrays, xcode, loops, view, swiftui

I am trying to find out how to get several arrays displayed on the same page with the scrollview style. Then, respectively  I would like to know how to display a single view page from each index array. Is that possible with SwiftUI? Cause for now, I just have an array with the scrollview style which displays the same page. This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct furnitureOrder: Identifiable, Hashable {
var id = UUID() 
let name: String
let imageView: String
 }

 struct itemOrder: View {

 @State private var showingSheet = false
 @State var items = [
    furnitureOrder(name: "", imageView: "1"),
    furnitureOrder(name: "", imageView: "4"),
    furnitureOrder(name: "", imageView: "6"),
    furnitureOrder(name: "", imageView: "7"),
    furnitureOrder(name: "", imageView: "9")]




   var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
       
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                DetailView(item: item)
            }
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Popular")
            .padding()
            }
               Spacer()
           
            }
     }


   struct DetailView: View {
    @State var showDescription = false
    @State private var showDetails = false
     
    let item: furnitureOrder

    var body: some View {

    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {

        Group {
        Spacer()
        Text(item.name)
        Image(item.imageView)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(width: 280, height: 140, alignment: .center)
        .cornerRadius(20)
                       
                        }
        Group {
            Image(item.imageView)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 280, height: 140, alignment: .center)
            .cornerRadius(20)

        }
         
       
        }
    

        .onTapGesture {
            self.showDescription.toggle()
        
}
        .sheet(isPresented: $showDescription) {
         itemOrder()
    }
    
    

    }
    
    
}

}
  


    struct furnitureOrder_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
    itemOrder()
}
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation before you publish a question. Currently your code is *very hard to read*.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Is that better?

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one ForEach within the HStack.  So add another ForEach below the existing one for your second array.  Within the second ForEach you can use the same DetailView or use a different view.